# Yii CGridView and Multiple Checkbox Per Row

Tags: checkbox, controller, yii

**Background**

I have a CGridView that contains multiple checkbox columns. I have created the checkbox columns using code like this:

```
$columns[] = array(
    'header'=>'Health',
    'value' => 'CHtml::checkBox("hsid[]", $data->healthService, array("value"=>$data->wc_client_id,"id"=>"hsid_".$data->wc_client_id))',
    'type'=>'raw',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center'),
);

$columns[] = array(
    'header'=>'Education',
    'value' => 'CHtml::checkBox("esid[]", $data->educationService, array("value"=>$data->wc_client_id,"id"=>"esid_".$data->wc_client_id))',
    'type'=>'raw',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center'),
);
```

The *$data->healthService* and *$data->educationService* are used to set the initial checked state of the checkbox, based on data from the database.

**Question**

How can I capture changes to each of the different checkbox in a row, and send those changes back to my controller? The controller would then update the database based on checkbox changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I finally got it to work:

**View Code**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'service-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$clients->search(),
    'columns'=>array(
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        array(
            'header'=>'Education',
            'class'=>'CDataColumn',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center'),
            'value' => 'CHtml::checkBox("esid[]", $data->education, array("value"=>$data->wc_client_id,"id"=>"esid_".$data->wc_client_id))',
        ),
        array(
            'header'=>'Health',
            'class'=>'CDataColumn',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center'),
            'value' => 'CHtml::checkBox("hsid[]", $data->health, array("value"=>$data->wc_client_id,"id"=>"hsid_".$data->wc_client_id))',
        )
    ),
));
```

**Controller Code To Retrieve Selected IDs**

```
$healthClientId = array();
if(isset($_POST['hsid']) && is_array($_POST['hsid']))
{
  $healthClientId = $_POST['hsid'];
}

$educationClientId = array();
if(isset($_POST['esid']) && is_array($_POST['esid']))
{
  $educationClientId = $_POST['esid'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be a better choice is a `CCheckBoxColumn` ?

See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCheckBoxColumn

Comment: v2p, I have tried using CCheckBoxColumn and was unable to control the column header. When selectableRows >= 2, the column header is forced to be a checkbox. I need column headers to indicate the type of service represented by the checkbox.